# how to fetch all the records of a HABTM association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model Products that has_and_belongs_to_many Categories .

The Categories table is set up so that a top level category can have an infinite number of subcategories that looks something like this

```
+----+------------------------+-----------+--------------+--+
| id |          name          | parent_id | top_level_id |  |
+----+------------------------+-----------+--------------+--+
|  1 | "Furniture"            |           |              |  |
|  2 | "Decor"                |           |              |  |
|  3 | "Lifestyle "           |           |              |  |
|  4 | "Electronics"          |           |              |  |
|  5 | "Sofas & Beds"         |         1 |            1 |  |
|  6 | "Chairs"               |         1 |            1 |  |
|  7 | "Tables"               |         1 |            1 |  |
|  8 | "Dressers & Wardrobes" |         1 |            1 |  |
|  9 | "Shelving & Storage"   |         1 |            1 |  |
| 10 | "Sofas"                |         5 |            1 |  |
| 11 | "Beds"                 |         5 |            1 |  |
| 12 | "Chaises"              |         5 |            1 |  |
+----+------------------------+-----------+--------------+--+
```

I would like to be able to query all products for "Furniture" for instance and get all of the products in "Furnitures" subcategories as well. Like wise if I queried "Sofas & Beds" I would like to get all of the sub cats like "Sofas" and "Beds"

This is my method for traversing this Categories table. This is just to build the menu to display and select all of the categories. I don't think it will help you much, but I thought I would include it to give you an idea of how I working with it.

```
module CategoryHelper

  def categories
    furniture = Category.where("top_level_category = ?", "1")
    decor = Category.where("top_level_category = ?", "2")
    lifestyle = Category.where("top_level_category = ?", "3")
    electronics = Category.where("top_level_category = ?", "4")

    def build_category_tree(top_level_category)
      categories = ""
      subcategories = ""
      top_level_category.each do |category|
        if category.parent_id == category.top_level_category
          categories << "<li class=\"shop_dropdown_category\" data-category=\"#{category.name}\"><a href=\"/category/#{category.id}\">#{category.name}</a><ul >"
          category_id = category.id
          subcategories = ""
          top_level_category.each do |subcategory|
            if category_id == subcategory.parent_id
              subcategories << "<li data-category=\"#{subcategory.name}\"><a href=\"/category/#{subcategory.id}\">#{subcategory.name}</a></li>"
            end
          end
          categories << subcategories << "</ul></li>"
        end
      end
      categories.html_safe
    end

    @furniture = build_category_tree(furniture)
    @decor = build_category_tree(decor)
    @lifestyle = build_category_tree(lifestyle)
    @electronics = build_category_tree(electronics)

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Ancestry**](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry)

First thoughts are you might want to look at the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) - this will give you the ability to associate as many categories with `parents` / `ancestors` as you want:

```
#app/models/category.rb
Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_ancestry 
end
```

This should allow you to create a table like this:

```
+----+------------------------+-----------+
| id |          name          | ancestry  |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
|  1 | "Furniture"            |           |
|  2 | "Decor"                |           |
|  3 | "Lifestyle "           |           |
|  4 | "Electronics"          |           |
|  5 | "Sofas & Beds"         |         1 |
|  6 | "Chairs"               |         1 |
|  7 | "Tables"               |         1 |
|  8 | "Dressers & Wardrobes" |         1 |
|  9 | "Shelving & Storage"   |         1 |
| 10 | "Sofas"                |       1/5 |
| 11 | "Beds"                 |       1/5 |
| 12 | "Chaises"              |       1/5 |
+----+------------------------+-----------+
```

As per the [docs](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#navigating-your-tree), you'll be able to use this to call some of the built-in methods for Ancestry, including:

```
@category.child_ids
```

---

**Menu**

You can then back that up by redefining your menu by using the following code we use:

```
#app/views/categories/index.html.haml
/ Items
= render partial: "category", locals: { categories: @categories }
```

--

```
#app/views/shared/_category.html.haml
%ol{ class: "categories" }
    - categories.each.each do |category, sub_item|
        %li
            / Category
            .category
                = link_to category.title, category_path(category)


            / Children
            - if category.has_children?
                = render partial: "category", locals: { categories: category.children }
```

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. The whole reason I did it the way I did it was I was having trouble getting ActiveAdmin to cooperate with Ancestry. Are you using ActiveAdmin with your setup.